# How to get total stock left using sql

Tags: mysql

I try to get remaining stock using sql.whats wrong with me.

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(quantity) as stock 
        FROM stock WHERE product_id='4' 
        GROUP BY product_id 
        - 
        SELECT SUM(qty) as sales 
        FROM order_details 
        WHERE product_id='4'
       )
```

Comment: hello @User6085744, can you please share a screenshot of the most important columns so I can give you an answer?
here product_id in stock is equal to item_id in order_details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you need.
Please provide table definitions and sample data and required output if it is not right.

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  SUM(st.quantity) as stock,
  SUM(od.qty) as sales
FROM
  stock st
LEFT JOIN order_details od
ON st.product_id = od.product_id
WHERE st.product_id = '4'
GROUP BY product_id;
```

We could also use the query following, which is closer to your original query.

```
SELECT 
  'stock' as "item",
  SUM(quantity) as "value" 
FROM stock WHERE product_id='4' 
GROUP BY product_id 
  UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'sales',
  SUM(qty) 
FROM order_details 
WHERE product_id='4';
```

Comment: But answer is not correct when you have more than 1 record for a product_id in the table stock (and this is suggested because you do a `group by` on product_id.)

Comment: Hello @Kendle,
That was a quick answer I had that but since you have posted as the answer I don't post mine, could you please change your query to this I have provided so you avoid any void or null values from any of those tables, here is the answer // 
SELECT
  stock.product_id,
  SUM(stock.quantity) as inStock_QTY,
  SUM(order_details.qty) as Sold_QTY,
  SUM((stock.quantity) - (order_details.qty)) as Remaining_QTY
FROM
  stock
inner join order_details
on (stock.product_id = order_details.item_id)
WHERE stock.product_id = '4'
GROUP BY stock.product_id, order_details.item_id; END//

Comment: @Axaitwork I used a LEFT JOIN because in business logic you shouldn't be able to sell a product that you haven't created in Stock. I don't know where you get `order_details.item_id` from and user6085744 says that it is working as I mentioned. When we group by a column used in the join there is no advantage in grouping by the equal column in the other table.

Comment: @AwatITWork when using your query result is getting incorrect..in my stock table 3 entry 5,5,2 respectively..Order details table has 2 entry 9,1.While using your query getting result inStock_QTY = 24 , Sold_QTY = 30 , Remaining_QTY = -6

Comment: I have posted the answer for you @user6085744.

Answer (score 1):

This is my nuclear weapon for dealing with getting the balance and stuff like that and you will never ever get any missing info for this, here is How I made it, I am doing this by creating 3 different Views, one for Order, one for Sold, and the combination of both (the final summary).

In the real example you have the ItemID in a table and that is the Primary key (not null no duplicate), you use that as a reference for all itemID get both sold and remaining.
for me, I have created **items** with **idItem (PK, AI) and itemName**

**First**, Create a view for stock **v_stock**:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `v_stock` AS
    SELECT 
        `items`.`iditem` AS `ItemID`,
        SUM(IFNULL(`stock`.`quantity`, 0)) AS `StockQTY`
    FROM
        (`items`
        LEFT JOIN `stock` ON (`items`.`iditem` = `stock`.`product_id`))
    GROUP BY `items`.`iditem`
```

Second, Create view for order **v_order**:

```
    CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `v_order` AS
    SELECT 
        `items`.`iditem` AS `ItemID`,
        SUM(IFNULL(`order_details`.`qty`, 0)) AS `SoldQTY`
    FROM
        (`items`
        LEFT JOIN `order_details` ON (`items`.`iditem` = `order_details`.`item_id`))
    GROUP BY `items`.`iditem`
```

Finally the summary view **v_itembalance**:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `v_itembalance` AS
    SELECT 
        `v_stock`.`ItemID` AS `ItemID`,
        SUM(`v_stock`.`StockQTY`) AS `inStock_QTY`,
        SUM(`v_order`.`SoldQTY`) AS `Sold_QTY`,
        SUM(`v_stock`.`StockQTY`) - SUM(`v_order`.`SoldQTY`) AS `Remaining QTY`
    FROM
        (`v_stock`
        JOIN `v_order` ON (`v_stock`.`ItemID` = `v_order`.`ItemID`))
    GROUP BY `v_stock`.`ItemID` , `v_order`.`ItemID`
```

Now, the idea here why I am using INNER not left or right is because or void or null in any of side (order or stock),

how I can get information? well easy:

```
select * from v_itembalance
```

Do I need the info for item 4?

```
select * from v_itembalance where ItemID = '4'
```

```
select * from v_itembalance;
select * from stock;
select * from order_details;
select * from v_itembalance where ItemID = '4';
```

[image: The query and final result]
[image: Table Item]
[image: Table Stock]
[image: Table OrderDetails]
[image: The final result]

Comment: "Now, the idea here why I am using INNER..."  what about stock where you do not have an order?  This stock will not show in your view `v_itembalance`

Comment: In the real example, the item_ID must be in the table i.e tbl_Item, and must be a Primary key, now you don't miss any ID with no QTY, let me update the answer if that is a case.

Comment: "....and must be a Primary key"  => not true

Comment: @Luuk, first of all, take a look at the answer, second, if you are talking about a structural database each table must have a unique key, it takes too long actually if you need I can create a chat for ya to discuss this take a look normalization steps. :P