# MySQL Join many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

producer:
[Producer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfzQe.png)

series_producer:
[series_producer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSca8.png)

and series:
[series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG8CW.png)

What i am trying to do is to do a select on producers and also show the names of the series they have created.
ex.

```
producer_id    producer_name    producer_series
1              Marta Kauffman   Friends, Dream On
```

I am able to show it with the id of the series, but i want the name instead..

This is my SQL to do that:

```
-- View all series from one producer
select producer_id, producer_name, group_concat(series_producer_sid) as prods
from producer w join
     series_producer uw
     on producer_id = uw.series_producer_pid
group by producer_id;
```

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the SQL you've used please?  And also some backgroung about the series_producer table

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, added it to the question now

Comment: looks like you just need to add another join from series_producer to series?  Not sure i fully undertand what you are after though :)     `select
p.producer_id, p.producer_name
from producers as p
join series_producer as sp on p.producer_id=sp.series_producer_pid
join series as s on sp.sp.series_producer_sid=s.series_id`

Comment: @LinusRomland I think my answer will help you a better understanding of this type of problem, here at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71498034/7828115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
  producer_id, 
  producer_name, 
  group_concat(s.series_name) as prods
from producer as w 
join series_producer as uw
  on w.producer_id = uw.series_producer_pid
join series as s
  on uw.series_producer_sid = s.series_id
group by producer_id;
```